# To add image to an excelsheet in iphone

Tags: iphone, image, excel, ios4

In my app I want to retrieve data from database and add it to an excelsheet.
The Database's data are in string and BLOB format. I have retrieve the data and added to excel sheet using the frameworks:
https://github.com/andreac/RSSheet

The problem is that I want to add image to the worksheet too.
If any one has any idea about this please help me.

Comment: convert image in data and add that data to worksheet.

Comment: I had done similar thing but the end user needs image not data.

Comment: [UIImage imageWithData:/*you data*/];

Comment: But how can I add this  to the excelsheet.

Comment: [[array componentsJoinedByString:@","] writeToFile:@"components.csv" atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

Comment: Shouldn't the last comment go as an answer? :)

Comment: we are not using csv, we do not require path but the image itself in excel sheet.

Answer (score 1):

The RSSheet library does not currently support adding graphics to the sheet. You'll need to do this on the server side unless you expand the RSCell class to support this.

Depending on your backend this can be done easily. In PHP I used the [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) library.